# What is use of MAP_NORESERVE flag in mmap?

Tags: c, linux, process, virtual-machine

> Do not reserve swap space for this mapping.  When swap space is
>   reserved, one has the guarantee that it is possible to modify the
>   mapping.  When swap space is not reserved one might get SIGSEGV upon a
>   write if no physical memory is available.See also the discussion of
>   the file /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory in proc(5). In kernels
>   before 2.6, this flag had effect only for private writable mappings.

I thought swap space is shared by all the processes in the host. After seeing this flag I would like to know:

- Is swap space is pre-reserved for each process? If yes,

  - how is the per-process reserve swap space is calculated?
  - what will happen if a process exceeds that reserved space? Will that process alone be killed or it will invoke OOM killer (kills a random process).
- Does this option only work with `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory -> 0`?
- What is the best use case for this flag?